# How do I use the returned values from the find function?

Tags: excel, vba

I just want to be able to search a range of cells for a value from a combobox then if found store it somewhere to be used in a bunch of other calculations but I can't get it to  work at all.

I really don't understand what the find function is actually doing. Does it return a range variable that identifies where the input has been found? And if so how do I reference/use that range?

Please don't just post code without an explanation I would really like to understand what is going on here.

```
Sub run_averages()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim rngFindValue As Range

    Set dd = ActiveSheet.DropDowns("thing")
    Set aa = ActiveSheet.DropDowns("otherthing")

    With Range("E3:DI3")
        Set rngFindValue = .Find(What:=" & aa &", _
            After:=ActiveSheet.Range("E3"), LookIn:=xlFormulas)
        With rngFindValue
            rngFindValue.Active
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try reading through [THIS](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/FindAll.aspx) which answers your questions. If however the link is broken, the answer to your first question is Yes, it returns a Range Object. You assign it in a variable using Set. You can then manipulate that range using Range Object properties and methods. Btw, if you want to pass values in ComboBoxes to a variable, you don't use set. Also the code differs to what type of ComboBox you use (Active x or Form Control).

Comment: Thanks a lot. They are form Control. So why do I get the error message : Object variable of with block variable not set ?

Comment: I think DropDowns is fine as I used the value in some other code... I just cannot seem to get any output from the range object without getting the error.

Comment: Yeah mybad but I'd rather use this: `Activesheet.Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat.Value`

Answer (score 0):

using the following code as you did:

```
    Set rngFindValue = .Find(What:=" & aa....
```

You reference found cell as Range. Therefore if you want to work with values of that particular cell, you can work with it as with any Range()  -> `rngFindValue.Value`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
Dim x As Long
Dim myitem As String, rngFindValue As Range

x = Activesheet.Shapes("thing").ControlFormat.Value
myitem = Activesheet.Shapes("thing").ControlFormat.List(x)

With Range("E3:DI3")
    Set rngFindValue = .Find(what:=myitem, after:=[DI3], LookIn:=xlFormulas)
    rngFindValue.Select '~~> or do whatever you want with your found range
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going nuts here ! I cannot understand the error messaging that I'm being given.

```
Sub run_averages()

Dim x As Integer
Dim rngFindValue As Range
Dim rngFindstart As Range
Dim myitem As Integer

Set dd = ActiveSheet.DropDowns("thing_length")
Set aa = ActiveSheet.DropDowns("thing_date")


myitem = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 1).Value

' using beans text to make sure error is not coming from drop down reference
Set rngFindValue = Range("E3:DI3").Find(What:="beans", After:=ActiveSheet.Range("E3"), LookIn:=xlFormulas)


With ActiveSheet
    .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(rngFindValue.Row, rngFindValue.Column)).Select

End With


End Sub
```

It is telling me that "Run time error 91 Object variable or With block not set" if rngFindValue is the only object i am using then it has been set by the fact  it is created..

What object does not exist ?

I am clearly missing something fundamental.

Thanks.

Wait. I'm a noob. There was no "beans" text in the document so it was giving me that error...